# No todas las rutas de acceso de codigo devuelven valor

Tags: c#, booleano

hice el programa en c++ y compilaba  pero cuando intenté pasarlo a c# lanzo el error con mensaje: No todas las rutas de acceso de codigo devuelven valor

```
    public static bool backtracking(List<Nodo> arreglo, int n, int actual, LinkedList<Nodo> resultado, int inicio, int c)
    {
        resultado.AddLast(arreglo[actual]);
        colorcito[actual] = 1;
        c++;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (colorcito[i] == 0 && relaciones[actual, i] != -1)
            {
                aristas[c] = relaciones[actual, i];
                if (c == n + 2 && i == inicio)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                backtracking(new List<Nodo>(arreglo), n, i, new LinkedList<Nodo>(resultado), inicio, c);
            }
        }
        c--;
        resultado.RemoveLast();
        colorcito[actual] = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Te falta el `return` al final de la función.

Comment: Si nunca entra a los ifs, nunca va a regresar un valor. Eso lo detecta el compilador.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 3):

Coloca el `return` fuera del `for` y los `if`. Sucede porque como esta dentro de una condicional puede que cuando no se cumpla la condición, la función no devuelva ningún valor, debería funcionar de esta manera:

```
public static bool backtracking(List<Nodo> arreglo, int n, int actual, LinkedList<Nodo> resultado, int inicio, int c)
{
    bool result = false;
    resultado.AddLast(arreglo[actual]);
    colorcito[actual] = 1;
    c++;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (colorcito[i] == 0 && relaciones[actual, i] != -1)
        {
            aristas[c] = relaciones[actual, i];
            if (c == n + 2 && i == inicio)
            {
                result = true;
            }
            backtracking(new List<Nodo>(arreglo), n, i, new LinkedList<Nodo>(resultado), inicio, c);
        }
    }
    c--;
    resultado.RemoveLast();
    colorcito[actual] = 0;
    return result;
}
```